# ASP.NET MVC5 Razor Refresh modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm tryin' to get actual time in modal dialog every time a user press the Order button.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#OrderModal">@MEDONET.Language.Doctor.Texts.Order</a>
```

So every time he do this in the modal div OrderModal

```
<div id="OrderModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    @Html.Action("CreateOrderForm", Model.CreateOrderVM)
</div>
```

Which calls to CreateOrderForm action

```
public ActionResult CreateOrderForm(CreateOrderVM createOrderVM)
    {
        createOrderVM.Minute = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
        return View("CreateOrderForm", createOrderVM);
    }
```

So that action is actually running every time and calls CreateOrderForm.cshtml file

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
@model MEDONET.Models.CreateOrderVM

<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Order To Line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateOrder", "Doctors", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DoctorId)
            <div class="row text-center">
                <p>Date & Time</p>
                @Html.Label("Year")
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = DateTime.Now.Year } })<br />
                @Html.Label("Month")
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Month, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = DateTime.Now.Month } })<br />
                @Html.Label("Day")
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Day, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = DateTime.Now.Day } })<br />
                @Html.Label("Hour")
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hour, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = DateTime.Now.Hour } })<br />
                @Html.Label("Minute")
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Minute, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })<br />
                @if (this.User.IsInRole("Registrator"))
                {
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })<br />
                }
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>
</div>
```

BUT! The popup fields are still filled with the first time given while parent page loading.

How can I give a user new time every time he press the Order button?

Comment: Where is your code that is calling that method each time you click the button? (`@Html.Action("CreateOrderForm", Model.CreateOrderVM)` is just calling it the first time you render the page)

Comment: And as a side note, never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods - you set the value of the property your binding to.

Comment: Also,  there should be methods decorated with `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` right?

Comment: Yes, it is the action of post   [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateOrder(CreateOrderVM createOrderVM)
        {
           ***
        }

Comment: I have tried to call it from javascript. It does work, it calls the action every time I press the button and action changes the model, but fields continue to stay with old values. I mean minutes. `$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateOrderForm","Doctors")',
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //some errror, some show err msg to user and log the error  
            alert(xhr.responseText);

        }
    });`

Comment: Start by removing the `CreateOrderVM createOrderVM` parameter from your method which will be setting the properties as their default value and those default values will be added to `ModelState` and its the `ModelState` values that will be used by the `EditorFor()` methods (setting the `Minutes` property in your code does not change that)

Comment: And the ajax call in your last comment does not update the DOM (you need to do that in your `success` callback)

Comment: Thank yal! I solved the problem :) Look at the comment at answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor code is executed only once, when page loads first time. After that, each time you toggle the modal popup, it just show/hide the same HTML. The solution would be to update the HTML, once you click the button to open the Modal. You can use JQuery's `load()` method to achieve this.

First you need to use JavaScript to toggle the Modal instead of HTML. Modify your button like below

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="openModal">@MEDONET.Language.Doctor.Texts.Order</a>
```

In JavaScript, add the event handler for this button like below

```
$('#openModal').on('click', function() {
  ...
})
```

Then, load the content of child action.

```
$('#openModal').on('click', function() {
  $("#OrderModal").load("@Url.Action("CreateOrderForm", "ControllerName")", function() {
    $('#OrderModal').modal('show')
  });
})
```

I haven't tested above code, and it may need few typo correction. Let me know, if it doesn't work.

Comment: I did this `<script>
    $('#openModal').on('click', function() {
        $("#OrderModal").load("@Url.Action("CreateOrderForm", "Doctors")", function() {
            $('#OrderModal').modal('show')
        });
        })` but when I press `<a class="btn btn-primary" id="openModal">@MEDONET.Language.Doctor.Texts.Order</a>`  nothin' happens

Comment: Can you change double quotes to single quotes like this `'@Url.Action("CreateOrderForm", "Doctors")'`

Comment: Yeah! Thank you! It works)) I set the single quotes, added the onclick method this way: `<a class="btn btn-primary" id="openModal" onclick="myFunction()">@MEDONET.Language.Doctor.Texts.Order</a>`
 and changed the function: `function myFunction() {
      
    //   $('#OrderModal #Minute').val(new Data().getMinutes());
       $("#OrderModal").load('@Url.Action("CreateOrderForm", "Doctors")',
           function () { $('#OrderModal').modal('show') });
       }`

Comment: I wanna do it, but can't :( I haven't earned 15 reputation to do that. Excuse me

Comment: @AzizjanHamidovichAyupov, You accept an answer by clicking the tick mark next to the answer! - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - you do not need any rep to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the method use some kind of post and than returns the new form.
In this cases it happens that when you return the same view the model state is the one that populate those fields. In order to solve it add in the action

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Or

```
ModelState.Remove("myChangeValue");
```

you can look for more info in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvcs-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value/

If you just want to change the time in the modal I would recommend to change it with javascript when you show the modal.

```
$('#OrderModal #Minute').val(new Data().getMinutes());
```

Comment: It supposed to work I think...How can I add the id to my Html.EditorFor ?

Comment: if your'e referring  to the first part, it is only when you have a post request. In the second you will need to add this line when showing the "modal". (to find the editor id: it usually the editor the chain of the model separated by "_" you can view with element inspector)